# Создание массива Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть вот такой простенький код, который устанавливает объекты на сцене. Мне необходимо, что бы каждый созданный объект, был добавлен в `list<Transorm>` а из этого листа последний трансформ записывался в отдельную `переменную` (например в отдельный трансформ или вектор) и при нажатии другой клавиши, последний трансформ из листа удалялся, перекидывая  данные `переменной` на позицию выше. Как это можно реализовать?

```
private GameObject Player;
private PlayerController PlayerController;
public GameObject SpawnPoints;
private Vector3 lastEndPosition;


void Start()
{
Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
PlayerController = Player.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
}

void Update()
{
    lastEndPosition = new Vector2(PlayerController.transform.position.x, PlayerController.transform.position.y);
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
    Instantiate(SpawnPoints, lastEndPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, вообще забил на лист трансформов, сделал всё через стак и мне кажется совсем неправильно, но это работает и работает как мне нужно))

```
private GameObject Player;
private PlayerController PlayerController;
[SerializeField]private GameObject SpawnObject;
private int Pos;
public Vector2 SpawnPoint;
private GameObject InstanceObj;
Stack<GameObject> Spawn = new Stack<GameObject>();



void Start()
{
Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
PlayerController = Player.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
}

void Update()
{
    Pos = Spawn.Count;
    if(Pos >= 1)
    {
        SpawnPoint = new Vector2(Spawn.Peek().transform.position.x, 
    Spawn.Peek().transform.position.y);
    }
    else
    {
        SpawnPoint = Vector2.zero;
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        InstanceObj = Instantiate(SpawnObject, 
    PlayerController.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        InstanceObj.name = "Point " + Pos;
        Spawn.Push(InstanceObj);
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        Destroy(Spawn.Pop());
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему вам кажется, что работает оно неправильно?) логика, которая была вам нужна соблюдена

Comment: Впервые столкнулся со Stack и это всё было написано, больше сказать, наугад)

Comment: Ну, это логика "последним пришёл - первым ушёл", существует ещё Queue<T> - это очередь с логикой "первым пришел - первым ушел". Т.е. в каком порядке объекты добавляются в том и извлекаются.